# Is there any Excel function that can copy column's (first row's) name if the value matches?

Tags: excel, indexing, row

I can't figure out a function that would automatically copy the first row value if the value on another rows matches 1. I would need the red dates to be automated.

Any advice would be very appreciated, thank you!

[Excel problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/20VGm.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with

```
=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(1; MATCH(1;E2:ZZ2)+4))
```

The inner **MATCH** searched for "1" in the given array (from E2 to ZZ2). The "+4" is there, because you are beginning to search in column E (=5) and MATCH returns the column within your array.

The **ADDRESS** takes the first row and the column found by MATCH.

The **INDIRECT** returns the value of the given ADDRESS.

If you copy this formula down the rows, the search array (E2:ZZ2) is automatically adjusted to search the corresponding row.

Answer (score 1):

```
=INDEX($E$1:$O$1;1;MATCH(1;E2:O2;0))
```

Replace semicolon with comma if your Excel version needs it.

[image]

If you have, you can also use Xlookup, it's a bit easier.

```
=XLOOKUP(1;E2:O2;$E$1:$O$1;"not found")
```

Comment: But using `INDEX` or `XLOOKUP` is preferable, only because `INDIRECT` Function is Volatile, and it Slows down the Excel Working Functionality! Nice!

Comment: I hope you know this one as well, but sharing with you, `=LOOKUP(2,1/($E2:$K2=1),$E$1:$K$1)` you could have shared this one as well!

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya Lookup is new to me. I read it is better and faster to use xlookup. Anyway I would like to understand why I don't get the same result when I multiply 1*($E2:$K2=1) or use --($E2:$K2=1), Do you know?

Comment: Try `Evaluating` the formula, from Formulas Tab --> you will find while evaluating its showing the for the `LOOKUP_VECTOR` as `{1,#DIV/0!,#DIV/0!,#DIV/0!,#DIV/0!,#DIV/0!,#DIV/0!}` while using `DOUBLE MINUS` or `*` it shall give 1 and 0, so the `LOOKUP Function` performs an approximate match and returns the corresponding values. LOOKUP has always been available in MS Excel. `LOOKUP` predates `V/HLOOKUP` and was one of the main functions in `VisiCalc` `(released in 1979)`. You are mistaking it for `XLOOKUP`.

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya I know, Lookup is old, but it is new to ME. I did the evaluation, both get a 1 for a match. So that 1 should give the same result in both methods, I think. But it doesn't. Still haven't understood why.

Comment: Please go through this, it might help you understand better [LOOKUP_FUNCTION][1]
  [1]: https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-lookup-function